# Cursor not looping as expected

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I have a simplified stored procedure for MariaDB / MySQL that should iterate all rows in a table and update one column value.  When the procedure is run, no rows are ever updated.  What could be the problem?

```
-- Here is a simple table definition
create table if not exists const_table
(
    id  bigint auto_increment,
    const int default 0,
    primary key (id)
);

-- insert 2 records. 
insert into const_table
(const) 
values 
(32), 
(64);


--/
create or replace procedure ps_daily_update_ex()
modifies sql data
begin
    declare id bigint;
    declare co int; 
    declare done int;

    declare c1 cursor for 
    select id, const
    from const_table;

    declare continue handler for not found set done = 1;
    
    set done = 0;
    open c1;
    
loop1: loop
        fetch c1 into id, co;

        if (done != 1) then
            set co = co + 25;           
            update const_table set const = co where id = id;
        else
            leave loop1;
        end if;
    end loop loop1;    
    close c1;
end;
/
```

I know that the cursor select statement is OK and returns two rows.

Comment: never name your variables like your column because id = id is alwways true as it is the same object

Comment: Seems like it wouldn't be that hard to run this without a cursor at all.

Comment: nbk, I changes the id value to "aid", still having the same problem

Comment: Do I miss something? Why a stored procedure if a simple `UPDATE  const_table SET const=const + 25` would do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it wouldn't be that hard to do this without a cursor at all:

```
update const_table 
set const = const + 25;
```

I know question this is probably a simplification of the actual production code, but as someone who has been doing database work for a long time now, I'd estimate fully 80% of the cursors I've encountered should never have been written in the first place, and that number may even be low.

Comment: Yes this is a drastic simplification, in the actual production code one in a number of columns are updated for each row based on one columns value.  So the cursor is needed.

Comment: You can use case expressions inside a single update statement to do the same thing without a cursor, where the default/else value of the case expression is the column.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, no database can determine which you mean then column or the variable, so name your procedurel varial with p_ at the start then you and the database know which object you mea

```
create or replace procedure ps_daily_update_ex()
modifies sql data
begin
    declare p_id bigint;
    declare p_co int; 
    declare p_done int;

    declare c1 cursor for 
    select id, const
    from const_table;

    declare continue handler for not found set p_done = 1;
    
    set p_done = 0;
    open c1;
    
loop1: loop
        fetch c1 into p_id, p_co;

        if (p_done != 1) then
            set p_co = p_co + 25;           
            update const_table set const = p_co where id = p_id;
        else
            leave loop1;
        end if;
    end loop loop1;    
    close c1;
end;
/
```

Comment: I knew I was doing something wrong.  I copied in your code and it works.  Thank you.